# data annotation and input[file]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view model with data annotation attributes

```
public class vm{
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false,ErrorMessage="message 1")]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "message 2")]
        public int Period { set; get; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "message 3")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\.xls|\.xlsx)$", 
            ErrorMessage = "message 3")]
        public string Extension { set; get; }
}
```

Period field is bounded to drop down list and with this field the build-in client validation works ok.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Period, Model.Periods, new { @class = "form-control", name = "period" })
```

I can get the error message throught ValidationSummary or ValidationMessageFor.

Now the problem I have with the fields Extension and Name. They are filled by my custom binder from submitted file.

```
 <input type="file" name="file" />
```

How can I manually bind these two fields to the input file tag that jquery unobstrusive client validation can work?

**UPDATE**

Just right now I found how to generate a input[file] with build-in helper by:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Extension, new { type = "file" })
```

But now the problem is, how can I bind the second field to it too?
I just want to have a single input bound to two fields in view model. How can I do that?
It doesn't seems to work even with hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Name)
```

Comment: If you don't render inputs for `Name` and `Extension` you cant associate `ValidationMessageFor` with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.
The solution it to use a hidden fields, but the validate plugin must be configured to not ignore them.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Name)
```

and in script

```
$('form').validate().settings.ignore = [];
```

If there is any better way to do it, I would like to see it.

Comment: You are using the correct setting for `ignore` so that it ignores nothing.